# Scala: Reflection APIs to call one of the two methods with the same name

Tags: java, scala, scala-reflect

I am trying to use Scala Reflection APIs to call one of the two methods with the same name. Only difference is that one of them takes an argument but the other one doesn't. I want to call the one that doesn't take any arguments. I am trying something like this:

```
  val ru = scala.reflect.runtime.universe
  val rm = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
  val instanceMirror = rm.reflect(myInstance)
  val methodSymbol = instanceMirror.symbol.typeSignature.member(ru.TermName("getXyzMethod")).asTerm.alternatives

  if (methodSymbol != null && methodSymbol.nonEmpty) {
    try {
      val method = instanceMirror.reflectMethod(methodSymbol.head.asMethod)
      val value = method()
      }
    } catch {
      case e: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException =>
        val method = instanceMirror.reflectMethod(methodSymbol.last.asMethod)
        val value = method()

      case e: Exception =>
    }
  }
```

This works but as you can see this is a bit ugly. The reason for doing it this way is that the 'methodSymbol' is a list in which the method I want is **sometimes in the 'head' position & sometimes in the  'last' position.**

How do I use Scala Reflection APIs to get only the method that I want which has no arguments?

Comment: Are you sure runtime reflection is required?

Comment: Can you filter by the number of arguments? It would always be the .head in that case.

Comment: @cchantep - Don't understand your question. Yes, reflection is required because I have 20 such methods that I need to call & I want to make this process dynamic.

Comment: Runtime reflection is rarely required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
  val ru: JavaUniverse = scala.reflect.runtime.universe
  val rm: ru.Mirror = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
  val instanceMirror: ru.InstanceMirror = rm.reflect(myInstance)

  val methodSymbol: Seq[ru.Symbol] =
    instanceMirror.symbol.typeSignature.member(ru.TermName("getXyzMethod")).asTerm.alternatives
  val maybeMethods: Try[ru.MethodSymbol] = Try(methodSymbol.map(_.asMethod).filter(_.paramLists.flatten.isEmpty).head)


  val result: ru.MethodMirror = maybeMethods match {
    case Failure(exception) => //do something with it
      throw new Exception(exception)
    case Success(value) => instanceMirror.reflectMethod(value)
  }

  println(result)
```

This will always return the method with no parameters.

Being like this:

```
def getXyzMethod() = ???
```

or

```
def getXyzMethod = ???
```

Adjust the size of the sequence if that method as more parameters, so if the method you want has exactly 1 parameter:

```
val maybeMethods: Try[ru.MethodSymbol] = Try(methodSymbol.map(_.asMethod).filter(_.paramLists.flatten.size==1).head)
```

And so on, hope this helps.

Comment: This is not working. Both of them have one parameter method "::".

Comment: Oh I thought the method was parameterless, like def getXyzMethod instead of getXyzMethod(), I will edit it

Comment: The Method is from a Java class. Not a Scala class.

Comment: @DilTeam updated the answer, you only need to change the size of the list, hope this helps.

Comment: Wow. You're awesome. Hope some day I will be as good as you're.